# qmake could not exec error while building Qt from source

Tags: qt, make

I'm having an issue building QT from it's sources. I have to build from sources due to a strange requirement (that's how we are going to do it at work, once we start using QT). Building from sources I get a myriad of issues, the current one being when I try to run qmake. Qmake throws back:

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
```

I assume that has something to do with a PATH variable but the README in the tarball says something different than the instructions on the website. I have been cobbling together instructions from different places to get it this far.

Has anyone built QT from qt-everywhere-opensource-5.4.0 on Ubuntu 14.04?